# How can i extract react route pathname in the queryString url?

Tags: reactjs

Here i am having a path like this and getting it from useLocation hook:

```
function usePageViews() {
  let location = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      GApageView(location.pathname)
    },
    [location]
  )
}

let path1 = /account/forgotPassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.ir1AeAKLZexUzGhjJvBuzm9jkqZahLAbRwTmOAjB8ZMpj3QLtkpymFwATNb_rP4fu0YgbRT4H9jetszOOSLEsg/ab/en/
```

in this above value , i need to get only the path route
Eg:

**Result:**

```
/account/forgotPassword
```

in someScenarios , the paths will be like this

```
let path1 = /account/login
let path2 = /
```

For this i need to get the value as it is.

Is there anyway i can achieve this.Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useLocation` hook from react router:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
...
const location = useLocation()
console.log('Path:',location.pathname)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am getting the value like this only. location.pathname will give the entire pathname. In this i want to get rid of that queryString.

Comment: Well , when you send the queryString, try adding ?key=string, and you can use path.split('?')[0], to get the pathname only. If you already know that your path is 2 parts only , use split to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to pass token, country, lang as query params. You can then simply use [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-route-issue-fix-jlgpu?file=/src/Nav.js)

**Component**

```js
const Login = props => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  return <div>{match.path.split(":")[0]}</div>;
};
```

**Route**

```js
<Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route
            path="/account/login/:token/:country/:lang/"
            exact
            component={Login}
          />
        </Switch>
```

**Nav**

```js
     <Link
        className={
          "tab " + currentRoute.includes("contact") ? "tab active" : "tab"
        }
        to="/account/login/eyJMiJ9.ir1LtEsg/ab/en/"
      >
        Login
      </Link>
```